# Resolve the reference of the library inside the NuGet package

Tags: .net, .net-core, .net-standard

.NET Standard 2.0 project uses a NuGet package with Library A v1.9 which references Library B. Library B has both v1.9 and v2.0.

When the project is built, it always picks up Library B v1.9. How to make it to pick up v2.0 instead.

I tried setting below properties in .NET Standard 2.0 project but no luck. When I build the project *deps.json is getting created and references v1.9.

```
<AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>true</AutoGenerateBindingRedirects>
<GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>true</GenerateBindingRedirectsOutputType>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know why its happening, please go through this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/concepts/dependency-resolution#direct-dependency-wins)
I think in your case, it is happening because of **Lowest applicable version**.
Reading the whole article will give you more clarity

If you want to explicitly use the 2.0 version, directly mention it in the .NET standard project file